# ASP.net MVC 4 Dynamic Views, Events and Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are building a large ASP.net MVC 4 Website where one of the modules for Questionaire needs to build the view dynamically.

We are trying to solve 3 problems:
- Generate the view using data from the database (Control Name, Value)
- Have events against the generated controls (Eg: radiobuttion needs to have a change event and needs to enable/disable items accordingly)
- Validate the controls (possibly client side validation)

What is the best approach to do this? We have thought about generating view using Html helpers and Editor templates. The other options floating are using dynamic model and custom model binders.

While we are trying things through POC, any thoughts and solution to solve the above problem will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice webcast from Brad Wilson : [Advanced MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/advanced-aspnet-mvc-3-presentation.html).
Also check the source for this presentation. You will be interested in NonClassModels part.   It shows how to wire all framework pieces around dictionary type. Validation, editors etc.

Hope this will help.